# How to calculate regularization parameter in ridge regression given degrees of freedom and input matrix?

Tags: ridge-regression

Let A be $n \times p$ matrix of independent variables and B be the corresponding $n \times 1$ matrix of the dependent  values. In ridge regression, we define a parameter $\lambda$ so that: $\beta=(A^\mathrm{T}A+\lambda I)^{-1}A^\mathrm{T}B$ .
Now let [u s v]=svd(A) and $d_{i}=i^{th}$ diagonal entry of 's'. we define degrees of freedom (df)= $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(d_{i})^2}{(d_{i})^2+\lambda}$ . Ridge regression shrinks the coefficients of low-variance components and hence the parameter $\lambda$ controls the degrees of freedom.So for $\lambda=0$, which is the case of normal regression, df=n, and hence all the independent variables will be considered. The problem I am facing is to find the value of $\lambda$ given 'df' and the matrix 's'. I have tried to re-arrange the above equation but was not getting a closed form solution. Please provide any helpful pointers.

Comment: Well I need time to answer this (probably others will be quicker to aid you), but most insights may be taken from http://www.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~kshedden/Courses/Stat600/Notes/prediction.pdf And what is $k$ in definition of degrees of freedom, since I do miss $\lambda$ somehow.

Comment: @Dmitrij: Thnx for the reply, I have updated the questions, and replaced 'k' with $\lambda$

Comment: Hi Amit, how can you know what the degrees of freedom are before calculating the regularization parameter?

Answer (score 12):

A Newton-Raphson/Fisher-scoring/Taylor-series algorithm would be suited to this.

You have the equation to solve for $\lambda$
$$h(\lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{d_{i}^{2}}{d_{i}^{2}+\lambda}-df=0$$
with derivative
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial \lambda}=-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{d_{i}^{2}}{(d_{i}^{2}+\lambda)^{2}}$$
You then get:
$$h(\lambda)\approx h(\lambda^{(0)})+(\lambda-\lambda^{(0)})\frac{\partial h}{\partial \lambda}|_{\lambda=\lambda^{(0)}}=0$$

re-arranging for $\lambda$ you get:
$$\lambda=\lambda^{(0)}-\left[\frac{\partial h}{\partial \lambda}|_{\lambda=\lambda^{(0)}}\right]^{-1}h(\lambda^{(0)})$$
This sets up the iterative search.  For initial starting values, assume $d^{2}_{i}=1$ in the summation, then you get $\lambda^{(0)}=\frac{p-df}{df}$.

$$\lambda^{(j+1)}=\lambda^{(j)}+\left[\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{d_{i}^{2}}{(d_{i}^{2}+\lambda^{(j)})^{2}}\right]^{-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{p}\frac{d_{i}^{2}}{d_{i}^{2}+\lambda^{(j)}}-df\right]$$

This "goes" in the right direction (increase $\lambda$ when summation is too big, decrease it when too small), and typically only takes a few iterations to solve.  Further the function is monotonic (an increase/decrease in $\lambda$ will always decrease/increase the summation), so that it will converge uniquely (no local maxima).

Comment: thnx a lot , but I have a doubt why do we need to assume $d_{i}^2=1$, since we have their correct values already...I have checked this formula by writing a matlab code and have not taken that assumption, but it works fine and gives correct solution

Comment: The assumption is just to get the initial value of $\lambda^{(0)}$ "close enough" to the correct value.  If you have a better guess, then start with that.  You could even just set $\lambda^{(0)}=0$, as long as your d's are greater than zero.  The d's are not assumed 1 in the iterations, just to get the algorithm started.

Comment: (+1) I would give the same numerical solution anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the small Matlab code based on the formula proved by probabilityislogic:

```matlab
function [lamda] = calculate_labda(Xnormalised,df)
    [n,p] = size(Xnormalised);   

    %Finding SVD of data
    [u s v]=svd(Xnormalised);
    Di=diag(s);
    Dsq=Di.^2;

    %Newton-rapson method to solve for lamda
    lamdaPrev=(p-df)/df;
    lamdaCur=Inf;%random large value
    diff=lamdaCur-lamdaPrev;   
    threshold=eps(class(XstdArray));    
    while (diff>threshold)          
        numerator=(sum(Dsq ./ (Dsq+lamdaPrev))-df);        
        denominator=sum(Dsq./((Dsq+lamdaPrev).^2));        
        lamdaCur=lamdaPrev+(numerator/denominator);        
        diff=lamdaCur-lamdaPrev;        
        lamdaPrev=lamdaCur;        
    end
    lamda=lamdaCur;
end
```

Comment: Go team!

Comment: An attempted editor argues that the while condition should be `while ( abs(diff)>threshold )`.

Comment: I am posting this as an alternative answer to the code posted by @Amit. I am suggesting that comparison to threshold in the `while( abs(diff) > threshold )` because the tolerance for the difference should be reachable from both the left and the right. For example let's say diff = $-100$ and threshold = $1e^{-16}$ then the loop condition is false, but clearly the solution has not converged.