# Degrees of Freedom for Ridge regression without knowing the Ridge Parameter?

Tags: ridge-regression, degrees-of-freedom

There is a very nice post here that gives a neat solution to the problem of finding the ridge parameter when the degrees of freedom are known:

[How to calculate regularization parameter in ridge regression given degrees of freedom and input matrix?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8309/how-to-calculate-regularization-parameter-in-ridge-regression-given-degrees-of-f)

My question is how can you know what the degrees of freedom are before knowing the ridge parameter value is? ( I have added a comment to the other thread but its quite old so thought it best to create a new topic).