# How to calculate regularization parameters in generalized ridge regression given the degrees of freedom and input matrix?

Tags: ridge-regression, regularization

I read a Q/A from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8309/how-to-calculate-regularization-parameter-in-ridge-regression-given-degrees-of-f) which is extremely nice.

In the above Q/Answer the tuning parameter $λ$ was a scalar. But in my problem it is a vector $\lambda$ for a generalized ridge regression case. The degrees of freedom is a fixed integer (assumed known).
I am struggling to set up an iteration search for vector $\lambda$ like the one given herein.

Comment: What is "generalized ridge regression"?